# Spring Bean Configuration: How to mark beans as mandatory/optional?

Tags: java, spring

I am making heavy use of Springs XML Configuration for Java Beans. Is there a best practice to mark a property of a bean as optional or required? I am currently initializing the optional beans in the default constructor. If one of the required properties it not set in most cases a NullPointerException will be thrown, but that doesn't really seem to be a good solution.

Sincereley,
Heinrich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the `@Required` annotation that you can use on mandatory fields.

Answer (score 2):

You can set bean `lazy`  which are not frequently required , they will be initilized only when they actually needed.

[Doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html)